# Am I assigning materials wrong? (Material will not display on object in any mode)

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

Blender version 3.0
OS: Windows 10
GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7900 (software version 21.5.2)
CPU: Intel i7-7700k

Hello, I have encountered a problem regarding assigning materials to my object that I cannot seem to fix on my own. What happens is that when I go to the material properties tab and add a new material, it does not show up on my object in object mode or edit mode using the material preview in the layout. My object turns into a grey silhouette.

[image: Pictured: the UV unwrap window, the node editor window, and the 3D viewport layout with a 3D object. The node editor displays that the Principled BSDF node is linked to a material output with the default white color. The object in the 3D viewport is not displaying the white material, and is instead a grey silhouette. In the collections, the object displayed is shown to have a material linked to it.]

I have gone into the node editor and tried assigning the principle BSDF and material output by placing the nodes in myself instead of using material properties to see if this fixes it. It does not. The material does not show up.

I have noticed that using no nodes allows the material to show up, but I want to use material nodes for this model. Assigning a base material in texture paint also works fine and displays properly.

**Important note:**
I do have a previous project that does show materials that are assigned to it, whether it is an image texture of just the settings of the principled BSDF but this previous project seems to be the only one that can display materials from the shader editor.

I have tried testing adding materials to the default cube in a new file to see if it is just this project that is the problem, and they will not apply, I get the same grey silhouette.

It seems like I am missing an important step in this that i have forgotten since my previous project, and all tutorials I have seen that concern assigning a material seem to just click "new material" in material properties and the principled BSDF assigns to their model with no issue. I do not think it is a gpu driver issue, since if it were, probably the materials of my previous project would not show at all.

Comment: It's your GPU drivers most likely. Try enabling "High Quality Normals" under _Render Properties > Performance_.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much.